# Error installing debug_inspector 0.0.2 Native Extensions?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Getting this error when trying to do a bundle install. Following the instructions to do a direct gem install fails as well. I have since wiped all ruby (and project code) from my machine including any ruby configuration and reinstalled ruby, devkit, and my project code. Still getting this. Not sure where to look next. Most searches turn up gem-specific solutions that don't seem to apply here. Let me know if I can provide more info. Thanks!

```
An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` succeeds before
bundling.

C:\TFS\Grange Commercial SEQ\White\Specifications>gem install debug_inspector -v
'0.0.2'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
ERROR:  Error installing debug_inspector:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/devl/Ruby/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in C:/devl/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
/debug_inspector-0.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/devl/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debug_inspector-
0.0.2/ext/debug_inspector/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is very old. However, I see two problems with this right off.

Windows doesn't have the tools (by default, or using the ruby installer) to compile c dependencies for ruby. If you want to do it yourself, you might check out: http://rubylearning.com/blog/how-do-i-install-a-ruby-gem-with-native-extensions-on-windows/

The other problem is that this particular gem doesn't work with ruby < 2.0: https://github.com/banister/debug_inspector and your ruby version appears to be 1.9.1

I would check your Gemfile.lock to see which gems are requiring debug-inspector. If you can do without them, take them out, and your bundle will succeed. If you must have them, try running a linux VM and using it for your development. My personal suggestion would be Ubuntu: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and VirtualBox or VMWare Player. Virtual Box is FOSS, so if this is company work, you'll have to use it: https://www.virtualbox.org/ . VMWare Player is free for personal use, and I like how it works a little better: http://www.vmware.com/products/player

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, using `Ruby 2.2.4 64bit`, on `windows 10 64`.

In my case what caused the error was installing several ruby versions, one after the other- (to try and solve that error)

Eventually I solved it by running `ruby dk.rb install --force` (At first I did that without the `force` flag), as stated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5571482/2502605)- Just make sure to use the correct ruby version- version that worked for me was `ruby 2.1.7 32bit`.

Comment: please use linux OS instead of windows 7/8/10